# adding content from search result with jquery

Tags: html, ajax, jquery

I am using this cool script http://qpoit.com/marcofolio_demo/apple_search/ however when I click on a search result, I want it to be added as html content to an id which I will use like . I know this is done with $("#displayContent").html(data); however I need the content of search result that I clicked on to be and not all the results found. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rpc.php-file of the search, contains the function, which generates the output of the search.
In line 29, change the content to a JavaScript-function, which does this work for you.

```
// Used in line 29 in rpc.php
echo '<a href="'.$result->url.'">';

// Change it to something like
echo '<a onclick="applyContent('.$result->url.')">'
```

After that, head back to the index.html (or the file in which you are using the apple-search), make sure jQuery is loaded and add something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Use the same function name, as in the php-file
function applyContent (resultURL) {
    // Use jQuerys get-function to get the content of the file you've found in the search
    $.get(resultURL, function(data) {
        // Change '#finalResult' to the css-selector, of the element, which should contain the result at the end
        $('#finalResult').html(data);
    });
}
</script>
```

Once you click on a search-result, it should make it the content of #finalResult, or whatever element you choose.

Comment: great! however I don't want the content of the file I've found, I just want the html  data that rpc.php retuns to be added to #finaleResult. How do I do that? I know the script does that but it fades away and I want the clicked result to be appended in #finalResult

Comment: oh wait, i got it. I want the exact same thing that stackoverflow is using for the keyword adding when you ask a new question.