# get selected content from ajax search result

Tags: php, html, ajax, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [adding content from search result with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14430105/adding-content-from-search-result-with-jquery)

I'm using this nice script http://qpoit.com/marcofolio_demo/apple_search/ however I want to display the selected value in a div with `$.("#result").html(selectedValue);` but I don't know how to get the selected value after the search results appear. Please help

Comment: Could you give us some code on how do you use qpoit.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display the text for the search result which appears in the `<span>` tag:

```
// Place inside the keyup method used for triggering AJAX call
$('#searchresults a').mouseenter(function() {
   $('#result').text($(this).children('.searchheading').text());
}).mouseleave(function() {
   $('#result').text('');
});
```

Comment: not sure I am doing this the right way, please help http://jsfiddle.net/qt59c/

Comment: Update your question with the formatted code

Comment: done see the jsfiddle link

Comment: What happens when you try: http://jsfiddle.net/qt59c/1/

Comment: nothing, the search results don't show up anymore.

Comment: Does it show any errors in your console. Can you create a new page with the code in the jsFiddle so I can see how it fails?

Comment: [00:09:02.742] SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list @ script.js:33 on this line         $('#searchresults').mouseenter(function() {

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/u8Scc/

Comment: How about now: http://jsfiddle.net/u8Scc/1/